# find method in mongoDB does not filter results

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have a method from which I am retrieving data from database like this.

```
const popularBookGenreDB = async (genre) => {
try {
    //Remaining to filters books by genre available
    console.log("{ genres: genre }", { "genres": genre });
    const enw = await Books.find({ genres: genre }).sort({ bbeScore: -1 }).limit(2)
    return enw;
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}};
```

It supposed to filter the results by looking if specific genre is in genres list of element but it only returns the items ranked by bbeScore. it does not take into account the genres list at all.

When I run same query `{genres : "Romance"}` on MongoDB Atlas find search field it works as expected. but when I try to run it on node server it does not take into account the genres list.

I have document as.

```
{
        "_id": "62b77562076177189c8f53af",
        "title": "The Hunger Games",
        "series": "The Hunger Games #1",
        "author": [
            "Suzanne Collins"
        ],
        "rating": 4.33,
        "description": "WINNING MEANS FAME AND FORTUNE.LOSING MEANS CERTAIN DEATH.THE HUNGER GAMES HAVE BEGUN. . . .In the ruins of a place once known as North America lies the nation of Panem, a shining Capitol surrounded by twelve outlying districts. The Capitol is harsh and cruel and keeps the districts in line by forcing them all to send one boy and once girl between the ages of twelve and eighteen to participate in the annual Hunger Games, a fight to the death on live TV.Sixteen-year-old Katniss Everdeen regards it as a death sentence when she steps forward to take her sister's place in the Games. But Katniss has been close to dead before—and survival, for her, is second nature. Without really meaning to, she becomes a contender. But if she is to win, she will have to start making choices that weight survival against humanity and life against love.",
        "language": "English",
        "isbn": "9780439023481",
        "genres": [
            "Young Adult",
            "Fiction",
            "Dystopia",
            "Fantasy",
            "Science Fiction",
            "Romance",
            "Adventure",
            "Teen",
            "Post Apocalyptic",
            "Action"
        ],
        "characters": [
            "Katniss Everdeen",
            "Peeta Mellark",
            "Cato (Hunger Games)",
            "Primrose Everdeen",
            "Gale Hawthorne",
            "Effie Trinket",
            "Haymitch Abernathy",
            "Cinna",
            "President Coriolanus Snow",
            "Rue",
            "Flavius",
            "Lavinia (Hunger Games)",
            "Marvel",
            "Glimmer",
            "Clove",
            "Foxface",
            "Thresh",
            "Greasy Sae",
            "Madge Undersee",
            "Caesar Flickerman",
            "Claudius Templesmith",
            "Octavia (Hunger Games)",
            "Portia (hunger Games)"
        ],
        "bookFormat": "Hardcover",
        "edition": "First Edition",
        "pages": 374,
        "publisher": "Scholastic Press",
        "publishDate": "09/14/08",
        "firstPublishDate": "",
        "awards": [
            "Locus Award Nominee for Best Young Adult Book (2009)",
            "Georgia Peach Book Award (2009)",
            "Buxtehuder Bulle (2009)",
            "Golden Duck Award for Young Adult (Hal Clement Award) (2009)",
            "Grand Prix de l'Imaginaire Nominee for Roman jeunesse étranger (2010)",
            "Books I Loved Best Yearly (BILBY) Awards for Older Readers (2012)",
            "West Australian Young Readers' Book Award (WAYRBA) for Older Readers (2010)",
            "Red House Children's Book Award for Older Readers & Overall (2010)",
            "South Carolina Book Award for Junior and Young Adult Book (2011)",
            "Charlotte Award (2010)",
            "Colorado Blue Spruce Young Adult Book Award (2010)",
            "Teen Buckeye Book Award (2009)",
            "Pennsylvania Young Readers' Choice Award for Young Adults (2010)",
            "Rhode Island Teen Book Award (2010)",
            "Dorothy Canfield Fisher Children's Book Award (2010)",
            "Evergreen Teen Book Award (2011)",
            "Soaring Eagle Book Award (2009)",
            "Milwaukee County Teen Book Award Nominee (2010)",
            "Sakura Medal for Middle School Book (2010)",
            "Michigan Library Association Thumbs Up! Award (2009)",
            "Florida Teens Read (2009)",
            "Deutscher Jugendliteraturpreis for Preis der Jugendjury (2010)",
            "Iowa High School Book Award (2011)",
            "New Mexico Land of Enchantment Award for Young Adult (2011)",
            "Eliot Rosewater Indiana High School Book Award (2010)",
            "The Inky Awards for Silver Inky (2009)",
            "California Young Readers Medal for Young Adult (2011)",
            "Lincoln Award (2011)",
            "Kinderboekwinkelprijs (2010)",
            "Missouri Truman Readers Award (2011)",
            "CYBILS Award for Young Adult Fantasy & Science Fiction (2008)",
            "Literaturpreis der Jury der jungen Leser for Jugendbuch (2010)",
            "The Inky Awards Shortlist for Silver Inky (2009)",
            "Prix Et-lisez-moi (2011)",
            "Missouri Gateway Readers Award (2011)",
            "Oklahoma Sequoyah Award for High School and Intermediate (2011)",
            "Premio El Templo de las Mil Puertas for Mejor novela extranjera perteneciente a saga (2009)",
            "Rebecca Caudill Young Readers' Book Award (2011)",
            "LovelyBooks Leserpreis for Fantasy (2009)",
            "LovelyBooks Leserpreis for Bestes Cover/Umschlag (2009)",
            "Premi Protagonista Jove for Categoria 13-14 anys (2010)"
        ],
        "numRating": 6376780,
        "ratingByStars": [
            "3444695",
            "1921313",
            "745221",
            "171994",
            "93557"
        ],
        "likedPercent": 0,
        "setting": [
            "District 1",
            "anem",
            "Capito",
            "anem",
            "Panem (United States)"
        ],
        "coverImg": "https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1586722975l/2767052.jpg",
        "bbeScore": 2993816,
        "bbeVotes": 30516,
        "price": 5.09
    },
```

Expected Result that I would get document that would contain genre item in (eg. 'Romance') document and no others.

example :

Expected :

```
 [
    {title : "Hunger games" , ... , genres : [... , "Romance"...]}
    {title : "Pride and Prejudice" , ... , genres : [... , "Romance"...]}
  ]
```

Returned Output

```
 [
    {title : "Hunger games" , ... , genres : [... , "Romance"...]}
    {title : "HarryPotter" , ... , genres : [......]} // No "Romance" in genres list
  ]
```

Routes.js file

```
    // router.route("/books").get(searchBooks)
router.route("/books/popular/:genre").get(PopularBookGenre)
// router.route("/books/popular").get(popularBooks)
router.route("books/autocomplete").get(autoCompleteBooks)
```

If this doesn't work How can I use aggregatePipeline to solve this problem. Again the query works in mongoDB online find search field for collection but not with node.

Answer (score 0):

use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to find documents , in which array contains specific value

```
const popularBookGenreDB = async (genre) => {
    try {
        const enw = await Books.find({'genres': {'$all':[genre]} })
        .sort({ bbeScore: -1 })
        .limit(2);

        return enw;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }};
```

Comment: It still returns me same array ranked by bbeScore and completely ignoring the filter inside as could not get this to work I ended up building aggregate Pipeline.    `const data = await Books.aggregate([
            { $match: { genres: { $in: [genre] } } },
            { $limit: 5 },
            { $sort: { bbeScore: -1 } }
        ])`

Comment: @J017 , check updated answer

Comment: Still returning same array , It's weird but your code works in aggregate Pipeline method but not in find method. I have created the Pipeline from the above code so it works now.

Comment: @J017 , in pipeline you have written limit first , then sort , in find you have sorted first then limit ... try `find().limit().sort()`